# How to use CalibratedClassifierCV on already trained xgboost model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, sklearn-pandas

I want to calibrate my xgboost model which is already trained. According to the documentation:

> If “prefit” is passed, it is assumed that base_estimator has been
>   fitted already and all data is used for calibration.

So I have tried to use it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV

X, y = make_classification()
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
X.columns = ['var' + str(i) for i in range(1, 21)]
y = pd.Series(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

calibrated = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, method='isotonic', cv='prefit')
calibrated.fit(X_test, y_test)
```

Unfortunetely, this resulted in the following error:

> ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4',
>   'var5', 'var6', 'var7', 'var8', 'var9', 'var10', 'var11', 'var12',
>   'var13', 'var14', 'var15', 'var16', 'var17', 'var18', 'var19',
>   'var20'] ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9',
>   'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19']
>   expected var12, var10, var3, var1, var20, var15, var2, var9, var16,
>   var7, var17, var11, var8, var5, var13, var4, var14, var6, var19, var18
>   in input data training data did not have the following fields: f2, f5,
>   f16, f17, f13, f11, f18, f6, f9, f1, f12, f10, f19, f15, f14, f3, f7,
>   f0, f4, f8

I believe this may be due to the fact that features are stored within xgboost object under default names `f1`, `f2` etc. Therefore, I have tried to rename `X_test` columns using `X_test.rename(lambda x: x.replace('var', 'f'), axis = 1)`, but it doesn't solve the issue. So my question is: how can I fix this error and use `CalibratedClassifierCV` on trained `xgboost` model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas causes the problem. You have column names passed to the sklearn models which is WRONG.

Use `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.values, y.values)` and everything will work fine.

You need to pass `numpy` arrays into any `sklearn` function for full compatibility.

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV

X, y = make_classification()
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
X.columns = ['var' + str(i) for i in range(1, 21)]
y = pd.Series(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.values, y.values)

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

calibrated = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, method='isotonic', cv='prefit')
calibrated.fit(X_test, y_test)
```